# What is HIP and why can’t you run it on the ryzen 3400g?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, opencl, amd-rocm

I am interested in running deep learning code on my Ryzen 3400g system.  Online I saw:

> I trying to use Vega 11 on my Ryzen 3400G, I'm aware that I cannot run
> HIP, but I possibly could run opencl on this APU, my first step is to
> import tensorflow, but I got an error,

This is from https://github.com/ROCmSoftwarePlatform/tensorflow-upstream/issues/669

Is it really impossible to use the ryzen 3400g with Radeon vega 11 gpu with tensorflow?

—————

Could it be made to work with opencl instead (as in https://missinglink.ai/guides/tensorflow/tensorflow-support-opencl/ )?

Answer (score 5):

According to the official [HIP Github page](https://github.com/ROCm-Developer-Tools/HIP),:

> HIP is a C++ Runtime API and Kernel Language that allows developers to create portable applications for AMD and NVIDIA GPUs from single source code.

And yes you can use `tensorflow` library like a normal python module, but you cannot use `tensorflow-gpu` which leverages Cuda cores available only Nvidia GPUs. And the Radeon Open Compute project is basically aimed at 'HPC and Ultrascale computing' and you can see the official supported GPUs [here](https://github.com/RadeonOpenCompute/ROCm#supported-gpus). They have also mentioned that the ROCm project does not support built-in GPUs.

> The integrated GPUs in AMD APUs are not officially supported targets for ROCm

So basically the answer is no, you won't be able to run `tensorflow-gpu` on your Ryzen 3600G system but you can use the normal `tensorflow` library without GPU acceleration. There are lots of threads discussing the issue so hopefully something will come up soon.

Comment: Thank you although it’s a real shame if it’s really impossible.

Comment: Yeah the ROCm project is a very early one which is still in development as of my knowledge and AMD as a whole is very late to the "leveraging multiple cores for deep learning" game.

Comment: What is the current status?